# How to use Couchbase function in index creation in Python?

Tags: python, couchbase

I'm trying to create [inverted index on a date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777035/how-to-get-latest-document-from-specific-date). It works in Couchbase admin console, but I'm getting error in Python code. I'm obviously doing it wrong with python, but I could not find any examples on using function with  index creation in Python.  Here is a working N1QL:

```
CREATE INDEX `mytabenter code herele_date` ON `mytable`(-TONUMBER(`date`));
```

Here is a broken Python code:

```
cb = Bucket('couchbase://localhost/mytable', password='passw0rd')
cb.bucket_manager().create_n1ql_index('mytable_date_desc', fields=[-TONUMBER('date_desc')], defer=True, ignore_exists=True)
```

function -TONUMBER generate an error "Unresolved reference"/ "NameError: name 'TONUMBER' is not defined".

What is the right way of creating such index with a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `TONUMBER` as it's a N1QL defined function and not in the Python SDK directly; the following example should work:

`` manager.create_n1ql_index(
    'mytable_date_desc', 
    fields=['(-TONUMBER(`date`))'],
    defer=True,
    ignore_exists=True) ``

Answer (score 0):

The `.create_n1ql_index()` is there for convenience, and not necessarily to be API complete.  It allows you to handle the most simple cases, but more complex ones are better handled by a string through the query API.